# TMaskEdit LookUpComboBox Behaviour

Tags: delphi, devexpress, lookup, delphi-xe5, maskedtextbox

I have a dev express grid dbtableview where I defined a column as maskedit. 
On InitEdit I populate the LookItems list for a specific record (item).

The question is if I can restrict the user to introduce only the values that match the LookItems for the specific record, instead of changing the whole column property to LookUpComboBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a component called cxEditRepository, add LookupComboBox to Repository
on your cxDBColumn use the event OnGetProperties

In this example, my column is called 'text'

```
procedure TForm2.cxGrid1DBTableView1TextGetProperties(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
  var AProperties: TcxCustomEditProperties);
begin
  if ARecord.Values[cxGrid1DBTableView1Text.Index] = 'value2' then
    AProperties:= cxEditRepository1LookupComboBoxItem1.Properties;
end;
```

I hope this has helped